# unsure of (id)init explanation

Tags: ios, init

So this is fairly beginner, but I'm trying to really grasp this concept. So in my sample code I have an Init method with two Constants defined at the beginning of the .m :

```
#define NUM_TOP_ITEMS 5
#define NUM_SUBITEMS 6

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        topItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self topLevelItems]];
        subItems = [NSMutableArray new];
        currentExpandedIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < [topItems count]; i++) {
            [subItems addObject:[self subItems]];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

What is the init method doing here? Could i initiate the two constants in their separate alloc/init methods? Any clarity here would be great! thanks

Comment: This code looks weird. Is that something you wrote, or does it come from some website? If it's not your own code, I'd suggest to invest in a good book about Cocoa instead. As it is, hard to say what it does without at least the "@interface" part, but it doesn't look reasonable.

Comment: Constants are, as the name suggests, constant, so you can't set their values after they are defined (and that has nothing to do with the `init` method)

Comment: Yea, this is not my code. Got it from a website...thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, line by line...

```
#define NUM_TOP_ITEMS 5 // defining a macro for the number 5
#define NUM_SUBITEMS 6 // and 6

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init]; // here you are initialising the object by calling the super class method
    // this is important as you still want the functionality/properties etc... from the super class.

    if (self) { //check the object actually exists.
        topItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self topLevelItems]]; //This looks like it's running a method called topLevelItems
        // that returns an NSArray. You are then saving it in an iVar (I guess)
        subItems = [NSMutableArray new]; // this creates a new mutable array in an iVar called subItems
        currentExpandedIndex = -1; // this sets an iVar int value

        for (int i = 0; i < [topItems count]; i++) { // set up a for loop for the topItems array
            [subItems addObject:[self subItems]]; //...wat?
            // not quite sure what's going on here.
            // I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing
        }
    }
    return self; // return the object whether it has been allocated successfully or not.
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir! So what object is  self==[super init] initializing?

Comment: Yes, `[super init]` will get called all the way up the "chain" until it gets to `NSObject` (the super class of all objects). This will then create an `NSObject` and then come back down the chain setting values and properties etc...

Comment: So is this a housekeeping task that needs to be implemented with every .m file? Only reason why I'm confused, is because some apps/exercises I do, I don't see a (id)init method called at all and they work just fine. Why is there one here?

Comment: Only if you want to customise the init method. If you don't want to add anything (i.e. you don't need to add any custom properties each time you create the object) then don't put the init method in there. Then it will just go straight up to the superclass and use that init method.

Answer (score 0):

Constants defined using `#define` are like a search and replace for tokens which happens at compile time. This is the [C pre-processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), it means that code like this,

```
#define NUM_TOP_ITEMS 5 + 1
int i = NUM_TOP_ITEMS + NUM_TOP_ITEMS;
```

gets pre-processed to something like this,

```
int i = 5 + 1 + 5 + 1;
```

before the next compilation step happens.